# Facing problem in Serializing a vb.net string to a json string

Tags: jquery, vb.net, json

i have the following code, please let me know where m goin' wrong..

VB

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dvItems.Table.Rows
   strItems &= "'" & dr("ItemTitle") & "',"
Next
strItems = strItems.Trim(",") // before serialize strItems contains 'mouse','keyboard','led'
strItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strItems) // after serialize strItems contains "'mouse','keyboad','led'"
```

JavaScript: Here i'm using Autocomplete.js using JQuery

```
function InitAutocomplete() 
{
   var Jsondata = [<%=strItems %>].sort();
   data = jQuery.parseJSON(Jsondata);
   AutoComplete_Create('<%=txtItem.ClientId %>', data);
}
```

while debugging in firefox with firebug `data` is showing null...What i'm doin' here ??

**Edit :**
Autocomplete.js needs `data` in this format 'mouse','keyboard','led'
Before i was doin' this without JSON, it was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is for parsing JSON strings. You're handing it an array. Your JavaScript code, once it gets to the client, will look something like this:

```
function InitAutocomplete() 
{
   var Jsondata = ["'mouse','keyboad','led'"].sort();
   data = jQuery.parseJSON(Jsondata);
   AutoComplete_Create('someid', data);
}
```

...which meanson `Jsondata` will be an array with one entry, the string `'mouse','keyboard','led'`.

If I understand what you're doing, you don't need JSON at all.

VB:

```
strItems = ""
For Each dr As DataRow In dvItems.Table.Rows
   ' Use JsonConvert.SerializeObject to quote and escape the
   ' string; even though we're not actually using JSON, it
   ' gives us a valid, properly-escaped JavaScript string
   ' literal.
   strItems &= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dr("ItemTitle")) & ","
Next
strItems = strItems.Trim(",")
```

JavaScript (with inline VB):

```
function InitAutocomplete() 
{
   var data = [<%=strItems %>].sort();
   AutoComplete_Create('<%=txtItem.ClientId %>', data);
}
```

or even just:

```
function InitAutocomplete() 
{
   AutoComplete_Create('<%=txtItem.ClientId %>',
                       [<%=strItems %>].sort());
}
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strItems)` is not converting to `JSON` string ??

Comment: @Crowder: i agree, but if items contains this `']` then my script is ending, thats why i'm trying to use JSON

Comment: @FosterZ: Right, you need to be sure that any strings you output are properly escaped (since you're outputting strings using `'` as the string delimiter, you have to ensure any `'` in the string has a backslash in front of it; you also have to be sure any backslash has a backslash in front of it). I can't find a reference page for `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` (surprisingly), but from the quotes in your question, it may well be able to help -- see the comment in the code above.

Comment: for this `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` i'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` and i guess i have to find sm other solution for escaping `']` coz i dn't think so that this `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` will help..

Comment: @FosterZ: Well, as far as I can tell, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(string)` should work, since according to the comments in the code in your question, if you pass a string into it, it's properly quoting the string (using double quotes instead of singles, but that's fine). Let me update the answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: @FosterZ: Updated. Meanwhile, looks like you've accepted this answer, so perhaps you got there first! :-)